# Php - How to adjust the content depending on the url

Tags: php, html, mysql

It's my first time posting here, but i've been using this website a few times.

Well I encountered a problem I dont really seem to be able to solve.
I want to send a text input to another php file called connect. that checks the database if it exists in there, upon existance=true it sends the user to the same page but with different content.

Currently I have in index:

```
<form action ="connect.php" method = "get">
    Name:   <input type="text"  class= "textfieldcss" style="width: 65%;" name = "name"><input type="submit" class= "button" value = "Connect!">
</form>
```

in connect:

```
<?php
include 'folder/folder.php';



            $conn = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,"name_database");

            // check connection 
            if ($conn->connect_error)
                {
                    echo "Connection failed: \n". $conn->connect_error;
                }

            $name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']);
            $sql = "select * from table where name ='".$name."'";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            //echo $numrows." results found for ".$name."</br>"; random testin

                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    if($name == $row['name']){ //returns name in database
                    header('location: index.php?name='.$name);
                    }}

                    header('location: index.php?name=');

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

well im kind of stuck at the if clause, i dont know how to properly code the value true/false into the original index.

I dont plan on using a href for creating multiple sites, since i plan to store over 200 values in the database

Comment: see this `$row['name]` this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you something as would http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Even Stack's syntax highlighter's showing you.

Comment: i adjusted the variables to name but yea musta went missing and edited the typo

Comment: either way, check for errors. I have no idea if your table name is actually called `table` or not.

Comment: it'snot called table  nor is the database called name_database, neither am i stuck at the database part, I am stuck at the part where if(inputdata == database data) { adjust the url to the inputdata with ?name="inputdata" and then load the page index.php?name="inputdata" that's different from index.php

Comment: I'm basically wondering how to implement content depending on user input on a page called index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have quite a few errors in your script.

After checking if the MySQL connection failed, you allow the script to continue, you need to exit out at that point by adding a `die()` or similar statement.

Your final `if` statement doesn't stop the loop once it finds a match, the following `header` call will override the previous since they are both setting the same header, you need to insert a `break` statement after setting the header inside the `if` statement.

You have not properly escaped the variable `$name` which can be used to perform SQL injections. `htmlspecialchars` just escapes HTML characters, not dangrous SQL characters such as quotes, you need to use the MySQL escape method.

And finally, if you are simply checking for existance of the record, there is no need to fetch the record, you could simply do this (note I am not using the OOE methods here, but the logic is the same).

```
if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
  $name  = $_GET['name'];
  $query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($name) . "'";
  $rs = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    header('Location: index.php?name=' . urlencode($name));
    die();
  }
}

header('Location: index.php');
die();
```

Comment: Thanks man this actually helped me

Comment: You're welcome, would you please accept this as the correct answer then?

Comment: Well the question is only partially solved, i'm still wondering how to change content depending on the website url lol

for example index.php shows me the main body,  with the additional content <div id="only shown when ?name=$name> and depending on the name i want it to display another type of content

Comment: just do the same thing you did here. `if (!empty($_GET['name'])) { output your content here }`